# Print Array Elements on one line

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm populating an array variable `$array` at some point in my code, for example like below

```
this

is

an

array

varaible
```

What if, I wanted to print out the array variable like `thisisanarrayvariable` as one liner

i took the below approach, but i'am not getting any out while the program is hanging

`for ($i=0;$i -le $array.length; $i++)`
`{ $array[$i] }`

obviuosly, i dont want to glue them together like `$array[0]+$array[1]+$array[2]..`

Hope i can get a better answer.

Answer (score 21):

#### Joining array elements with no separator

Use the [`-join` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_join)...

```powershell
$array -join ''
```

...or the static [`String.Join` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.join)...

```powershell
[String]::Join('', $array)
```

...or the static [`String.Concat` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.concat)...

```powershell
[String]::Concat($array)
```

For all of the above the result will be a new `[String]` instance with each element in `$array` concatenated together.

#### Fixing the `for` loop

Your `for` loop will output each element of `$array` individually, which will be rendered on separate lines.  To fix this you can use [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) to write to the console, passing [`-NoNewline`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host#-nonewline) to keep the output of each iteration all on one line...

```powershell
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $array.Length; $i++)
{
    Write-Host -NoNewline $array[$i]
}
Write-Host
```

The additional invocation of `Write-Host` moves to a new line after the last array element is output.

If it's not console output but a new `[String]` instance you want you can concatenate the elements yourself in a loop...

```powershell
$result = ''
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $array.Length; $i++)
{
    $result += $array[$i]
}
```

The `+=` operator will produce a new intermediate `[String]` instance for each iteration of the loop where `$array[$i]` is neither `$null` nor empty, so a [`[StringBuilder]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host#-nonewline) is more efficient, especially if `$array.Length` is large...

```powershell
$initialCapacity = [Int32] ($array | Measure-Object -Property 'Length' -Sum).Sum
$resultBuilder = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Text.StringBuilder' -ArgumentList $initialCapacity
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $array.Length; $i++)
{
    $resultBuilder.Append($array[$i]) | Out-Null # Suppress [StringBuilder] method returning itself
}
$result = $resultBuilder.ToString()
```

Comment: used the `join` without any luck

Comment: What did you try?  And what was the result?

Comment: My bad..My earlier comment was without using the `-join $array` and `[string]$srray`, but with `[string]$array` i'am getting spaces in between elements

Comment: `-join ','` to retrieve an array in CSV format. For quoted CSV: `$inner = $tokens -join '","'; $output = """$inner"""; $output`

Answer (score 5):

Just use

```
-join $array
```

which will glue all elements together.